# MySQL – can't view data from different table because job number has suffix

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have job number, first is a planning table second is a stock table. Planing table, when the same job gets planned second, third time system adds suffix (letters A,B,C) to the job number. The data looks something like this.

Plan

| PlanDate | JobNo |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-08 | 666 |
| 2021-07-08 | 666A |
| 2021-07-08 | 777 |

Stock

| JobNo | Film |
| --- | --- |
| 666 | LHH |
| 666 | OBA |
| 777 | TBA |

MySQL Code

```
Select
 p.Date
 p.JobNo
 s.Film
From Plan p
 Left Join Stock s on p.JobNo=s.JobNo
Where date (p.PlanDate) = curedate()
Order by p.JobNo
```

This code answer would look like this

| Date | JobNo | Film |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-08 | 666 | LHH |
| 2021-07-08 | 666 | OBA |
| 2021-07-08 | 666A |  |
| 2021-07-08 | 777 | TBA |

I am looking to get this answer

| Date | JobNo | Film |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-08 | 666 | LHH |
| 2021-07-08 | 666 | OBA |
| 2021-07-08 | 666A | LHH |
| 2021-07-08 | 666A | OBA |
| 2021-07-08 | 777 | TBA |

I was trying to use `TRIM` but it was trimming only the letter at the end and still the answer was the same. Is there a way to get that result?
I cant make any changes on the system and tell not to add suffixes.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: "Structured" query language relies on structured data.

Comment: @danblack not my system I can't change it, I know its stupid but just trying to find a way to solve this.

Comment: `... ON (0 + Plan.JobNo) = Stock.JobNo ...`

Comment: `TRIM(trailing 'A' from p.JobNo) = s.JobNo` seems to work for me.

Comment: sorry @RickN you code didnt work

Comment: @Akina thanks a mil, that worked perfectly, could you please explain what is happening with this statement it is so simple, but I don't understand why its working.

Comment: *what is happening with this statement* When we use `0 + string_column` the expression have numeric context, and string column is converted to a number implicitly. In this case all leading digits (and also unary minus, decimal point, leading spaces) are treated as a value, and all chars starting from first non-numeric one are simply truncated. But if some leading char is not legal for numeric value then the expression produces incorrect output (for example, double leading minus produces zero) or causes an error - so use it with caution.

Comment: Had to read it 3 times but I got it now, thanks again @Akina